# How do I display the name of the column/s from which SQL found a MIN value?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of products and prices. It contains  10 different columns of prices. I'm able to successfully find the lowest value of all 10 price columns.

So, from this data:

```
Prod. Name | Week1  | Week2  | Week N | Week 10
Pizza      | $1.29  | $1.29  | $1.42  | $1.01
```

And I can display:

```
Prod. Name | Lowest Price
Pizza      | $1.01
```

But how can I also add another column to display the column/s from which the lowest value came?

Ideal output would be as follows:

```
Prod. Name | Lowest Price | From Week
Pizza      | $1.01        | 10
```

The search query I'm using to display the output is:

`SELECT ProdName, LEAST(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10) FROM results;`

**Edit:** 
I forgot to mention that I'm working with around 1,600 rows of data in total. This certainly makes coding it a bit more complex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to compare not only simple values but also records:

```
with t(x,y,z) as (values(1,3,2),(5,2,3))
select *, least((x,'x'::text),(y,'y'::text),(z,'z'::text)) from t;
```

```
╔═══╤═══╤═══╤═══════╗
║ x │ y │ z │ least ║
╠═══╪═══╪═══╪═══════╣
║ 1 │ 3 │ 2 │ (1,x) ║
║ 5 │ 2 │ 3 │ (2,y) ║
╚═══╧═══╧═══╧═══════╝
```

If it is not enough then you could to convert it to `jsonb` for example and retrive the values in the separate rows:

```
with t(x,y,z) as (values(1,3,2),(5,2,3))
select *, j->>'f1' as val, j->>'f2' as fld
from t, to_jsonb(least((x,'x'::text),(y,'y'::text),(z,'z'::text))) as j;
```

```
╔═══╤═══╤═══╤══════════════════════╤═════╤═════╗
║ x │ y │ z │          j           │ val │ fld ║
╠═══╪═══╪═══╪══════════════════════╪═════╪═════╣
║ 1 │ 3 │ 2 │ {"f1": 1, "f2": "x"} │ 1   │ x   ║
║ 5 │ 2 │ 3 │ {"f1": 2, "f2": "y"} │ 2   │ y   ║
╚═══╧═══╧═══╧══════════════════════╧═════╧═════╝
```

And for your data it could be:

```
select ProdName, j->>'f1' as val, j->>'f2' as fld
from results, to_jsonb(least((d1,'d1'),(d2,'d2'),(d3,'d3'),...,(d10,'d10')));
```

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I create a table with 5 prices

```
create temp table p (id text, p1 float, p2 float, p3 float, p4 float, p5 float);
insert into p values ('Pizza', 1.4, 2, 1.3, 2.1, 1.6);
insert into p values ('Tea', 1.4, 3, 3, 2.1, 1.6);
```

First UNPIVOT then table as an array, with the week names and the price of every week.

```
select
    id,
    unnest(array['week1','week2','week3','week4','week5']),
    unnest(array[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5])
from p

+-------+--------+--------+
|   id  | unnest | unnest |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Pizza |  week1 |   1,4  |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Pizza |  week2 |    2   |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Pizza |  week3 |   1,3  |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Pizza |  week4 |   2,1  |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Pizza |  week5 |   1,6  |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  Tea  |  week1 |   1,4  |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  Tea  |  week2 |    3   |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  Tea  |  week3 |    3   |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  Tea  |  week4 |   2,1  |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  Tea  |  week5 |   1,6  |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

Then filter this table result for the lowest price.

```
where cte.price = (select least(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) from p where p.id = cte.id);
```

You can check it here: http://rextester.com/VKXK37428

```
with cte (id, week, price) as
(
select
    id,
    unnest(array['week1','week2','week3','week4','week5']),
    unnest(array[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5])
from p
)
select id, week, price
from cte
where cte.price = (select least(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) from p where p.id = cte.id);
```

This is the result:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|   id  |  week | price |
+-------+-------+-------+
| Pizza | week3 |   1,3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|  Tea  | week1 |   1,4 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: hi. update with another row and grouping? `insert into p values ('Tea', 1.9, 2, 1.3, 0.3, 1.6);` I have a feeling the question was not about the only row

Comment: you can check it again

Comment: is week number another column in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Late night. Seems like a wheel, but anyway - the way to do it with json:

```
a=# select * from results ;
 i | e | f | Prod .Name
---+---+---+------------
 2 | 1 | 3 | Pizza
 2 | 3 | 4 | Beer
(2 rows)

a=# select "Prod. Name","Lowest Price","From Week" from (
with p as (select "Prod .Name" as n,row_to_json(results) p from results)
select
  p.n as "Prod. Name"
, min(case when j.value::text != concat('"',p.n,'"') then j.value::text::float end) over(partition by p.n) "Lowest Price"
, case when j.value::text != concat('"',p.n,'"') then j.value::text::float end compare
, j.key::text "From Week"
from p, json_each(p.p) as j
) s
where compare = "Lowest Price"
;
 Prod. Name | Lowest Price | From Week
------------+--------------+-----------
 Beer       |            2 | i
 Pizza      |            1 | e
(2 rows)
```